# Timepicker Addon with DatePicker

Tags: jquery, html

At the moment I'm using DatePicker (view-source:http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/default.html) but I'm having difficulties adding Timepicker addon (https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon), How can I use the addon properly ?

Thank you :)

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than that, for starters. What kind of issues are you having?

Comment: I've added the addition css, but having issues to figure out the right method to integrate both (datepicker & timePicker) .js together.

Comment: include the javascript and css files to your document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>  
<!-- core, slider, datepicker -->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/timepicker.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() {  
    $('#datetime').datetimepicker({  
      showSecond: true,
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
      stepHour: 2,
      stepMinute: 10,
      stepSecond: 10
      ...  
     });  
});  
</script>  

<input type="text" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="">
```

read its documentation here:
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: I've read that part but how do I include the addon .js with datepicker.js ?

Comment: <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script> No?

Comment: its included here: js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js

Comment: I used [link](http://code.google.com/p/simpleinvoices/source/browse/trunk/public/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js?spec=svn3898&r=3898#2) for jquery-1.7.2.min.js , [link](http://code.google.com/p/ga-api-javascript-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/explorer/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js?r=4) for jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js and  [link](https://raw.github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js) for timepicker but still no luck.